# How can I change the formatting of an existing solution in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin

I have a problem with the formatting code. I want to delete white space after function name. 
example private void Test (); 
When I create new solution, I can change for correct formatting. But I have existing solution change in Preference not working. 
I found something in forum https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7751/remove-extra-space-after-function-names but there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by selecting the portion of code you want to format and from Menu *Edit -> Format -> Format Selection*

Hope it helps

Comment: unfortunately it not help.

Comment: why? do you have an issue with installed version ?